# Dockerized nginx image fetches the config file of an entirely different app

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I'm using Docker for two apps I'm currently working on, each in a different folder, sharing the same parent:

```
projects/
    app_one/
        docker-compose.yml
        config/
            .Dockerfile-nginx
            nginx.conf
    app_two/
        docker-compose.yml
        nginx/
            .Dockerfile-nginx
            nginx.conf
```

I usually start working on app_one: 
`projects/app_one$ sudo docker-compose build && docker-compose up` 
then shut if off `projects/app_one$ docker-compose down` and start working on app_two: `projects/app_two$ sudo docker-compose build && docker-compose up`.

When I do this, the nginx container of app_two still has the nginx.conf file of app_one. I found out about this when I checked the dockerized nginx `/etc/nginx/` directory because my django app refused to load my app_two's static files.

Here's the nginx part of my docker-compose of my app_two:

```
nginx: 
  build:
    context: ./nginx
    Dockerfile: .Dockerfile-nginx
```

And here's its Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

Can someone tell me what's causing this behavior that, in my opinion, defies the very purpose of Docker?

**update**
I renamed app_one's nginx.conf, and but this has no effect. app_two still has the "old" nginx.conf of app_one.

Comment: Does app_two still build if you rename / remove the nginx.conf from app_one? Also, you mentioned *When I do this* - does your app_two use the right nginx.conf when you *don't do this* ?

Comment: Sure. Actually, I'm working on this app_two on different machines, and it does not show such behavior. It's even deployed on a production VPS, running like a charm. This happens only on the machine I'm currently on.

Comment: I just did what you suggested: renamed the other app's config file; the app_two still builds with the first app's "old" nginx.conf.

Comment: You're not setting `container_name:` in the `docker-compose.yml`, are you?  (Other than port conflicts, is anything keeping you from running both projects together?)

Comment: No, I don't use `container_name` because it prevents from scaling containers to more than one instance.

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to find out the cause of this issue. It's in my app_one's docker-compose.yml:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    build:   
        context: ./config
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-nginx
```

It turns out specifying both `image` and `build` directives means that Docker builds the image, then tags it with the `image`.

In this case, app_two's Dockerfile was basing its image on the one built by app_one. Removing the `image` directive of the app_one docker-compose file fixed the issue.